# Match pattern in Office365 Transport rule

Tags: regex, office365, exchange-server

I am looking to match header value with SCL -1 to 4 i.e. should match `SCL:-1`, `SCL:0` to `SCL:4` in a Office365 Transport Rule.

**Header value example:**

`CIP:209.85.214.169;IPV:NLI;CTRY:US;EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(2980300002)(189003)(199004)(476003)(59536001)(126002)(305945005)(16586007)(486006)(42186006)(246002)(106002)(61266001)(98316002)(95326003)(104016004)(84326002)(8576002)(7596002)(71190400001)(6916009)(6666004)(356004)(5000100001)(7636002)(2361001)(86362001)(564344004)(106466001)(2351001)(498394004)(336012)(33964004)(33896004)(1096003)(8676002)(55446002)(16003)(26005)(93516011)(61726006)(9686003)(5660300001)(579124003);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:DM3PR14MB0986;H:mail-pl1-f169.google.com;FPR:;SPF:Pass;LANG:en;PTR:mail-pl1-f169.google.com;MX:1;A:1;`

We don't know any other values except **SCL** and can not expect other values to be present.

The problem is that MS does not allow all regex characters and symbols https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/aa997187(v=exchg.141). It does not allow wildcards at the beginning of the regular expression. And also it does not allow multiple group matching.

Here is what I tried.

1) `[^\n]+SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)`: Doesn't work. Should be because \n and [] is not recognized.

2) `[^aa]+SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)`: Doesn't work. Should be because [] is not recognized.

3) `()+SCL:1`: Does not allow this expression.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)` or `^(\s|\S)*SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)`

Comment: @revo First does not work. Second is not accepted (multiple group conditions).

Comment: If second doesn't match which means `*` quantifier is not able to quantify a cluster then there is no chance to accomplish the task. If there is no whitespace characters in the string you provided then try `^\S*SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)`

Comment: `^\S*SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)` doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide any working pattern? Do this `^` or `\S*` match?

Comment: `^\S*$` pattern works.

Comment: So this should work too (if `*` works as a quantifier): `^\S*SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)\S*$`

Comment: Strangely `^\S*SCL:(-1|0|1|2|3|4)\S*$` does not work.

Comment: `^\S*;\S*$` works but `^\S*SCL\S*$` does not. Turns out `SCL` is actually not set when Transport rule processes the header.